# Calling fragment method without instantiating actual fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am not a very advanced user in android, and i don't know if this is the optimal way, but i have a problem with my structure. When doing webapps and desktop apps, i have been used to separate logic and presentation from each other, and i try to do this in android.

So far i have the logic for each "view" inside each fragment, so i want to have a onClick function for each button in each activity (as this is recommended by google), to only make a method call into each fragment, and handle the logic from there.. The problem is when i use the navigation drawer, and the recommended implementation of interfaces, i am not able to reach the functions, as i am not implementing the class, but working towards the fragment interface.

So far i have this for handling menu clicks and changing fragments:

```
private void displayFragment(int menuId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (menuId) {
        case R.id.nav_search:
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_create_ticket:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            LogoutDialogFragment logoutDialogFragment = new LogoutDialogFragment();
            logoutDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Logud");
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

So of course i am only able to call methods implemented from the interface, and not the public functions of my "searchfragment" class.. I don't think this is the right way, but what i want to achieve is something like this:

```
public void searchBtnClicked(View view) {
    fragment.searchForLicensePlate();
}
```

Is there a better way? I don't think i should instantiate a searchfragment inside the searchBtnClicked method, as the fragment already has been started in the displayFragment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- The drawer (NavigationView) is a ViewGroup, you can add a Fragment inside of it and then do whatever you want.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/drawerFragment"
            android:name="cl.cutiko.someapp.views.main.drawer.DrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

2.- If you want to use the default implementation then you don't need to have each function in a fragment, you can use a Presenter and return the result of the presenter to the View. See MVP design pattern [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/)

Comment: that seems like a very nice solution! thanks! i will have a look at MVP! :)

Comment: Every Fragment or Activity is a View, the View is plain dumb, show elements, hide elements, set texts, change colors, but no logic, not a single if. The Presenter is a Java class which take cares of the logic of the View. To report the result of the Presenter back to the View you have to use an Interface. The interface is implemented in the View (Activity or Fragment) and pass as an argument to the constructor of the Presenter. Is usually called a "contract". Good Luck :)